# Saving data generated through code into a particular location in your computer in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have created an app for generating a QRCode in Xcode.My problem is I can only view this QRCode through simulator,I dont know how to save these generated QRCode in a location inside my computer.
Please Help me.......

Comment: share codebase to understand what exactly you are expecting.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "core-data"?

Comment: iOS Simulator is not sandboxed. You can write to any path you want.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I tried the below code,but i am not able to find that data in the specified location.NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
[fileManager createFileAtPath:@"/Users/Me/Desktop/myimage.png" contents:myImageData attributes:nil];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1) You can save like this,

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
[fileManager createFileAtPath:@"/Users/Me/Desktop/myimage.png" contents:myImageData attributes:nil];
```

OR

Option 2) Save inside simulator/app, then access using finder

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

This is the Path (on Mac) where you can Find every thing Related to your Device Installation or apps Deployed by you on the Simulator :

/Users/"Your Home NAme "/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Which version you use(4.3.2 "this is mine")/Applications

Comment: hi..I checked your code.But i m not able to find that data in the specified location...can you tell me what is the problem with my code..   UIImage *my=[UIImage imageNamed:@"generator.png"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(my);
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:@"/dheeraj$ /haritha /myimage.png" contents:myImageData attributes:nil];